# How to maintain Bot Framework Composer built bot code on GitHub?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I was able to create a bot using the Enterprise Assistant (EA) C# Bot Framework Composer template but the project has some big files e.g. onnxruntime.dll, etc. that is not allowing me to commit it to GitHub.

Can anyone explain how to host the EA template bot on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is don't commit the DLLs or other large files to Github, as well as folders like bin and obj, which will be regenerated when you build the bot. Make use of a `.gitignore` file to limit what you commit to your non-sensitive project files alone. If you're working with any teammates, they would need to have copies of those DLLs. Since they would have the same `.gitignore` file, they would not commit the DLLs either.

Comment: is there a standard .gitignore file for C# bot projects. I haven't worked on C# and am just using the Composer to get my bot built. I want other users to be able to clone the repo and run the code. Is there something like npm install for C# projects that installs the dependencies?

Comment: Github's official collection of [gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know what can be safely ignored so other people can just open the Bot in Composer and run it. Does Composer reinstall the dependencies?

Comment: Where exactly are these "too large" files coming from? The official [samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/composer-samples/csharp_dotnetcore/projects) has Composer samples that can be downloaded and run immediately without needing to add extra DLLs. These samples make use of QnA, LUIS, and other important features. So it is possible, at the very least.

Comment: The git error I'm getting is \n Git: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

Comment: To reproduce, create a bot using the Enterprise Assistant template for C#, make sure it works and then try uploading it to GitHub

Comment: I just gave it a try. In the root as well as both skills, you can open all three `gitignore` files and ignore the `bin` and `obj` folders, as well as the DLLs, and the `appsettings.json` files, and commit the remaining files to Github. Someone else will be able to download the bot, supply their own LUIS and QnA credentials, and build and run the bot.

Comment: Getting this error now. Can the models be ignored too?
EnterpriseAssistant/model/pretrained.20200924.microsoft.dte.00.06.en/model.onnx is 255.46 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Comment: Since that one file is greater than 100MB, it would appear that you have no choice but to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked... please update the answer to ignore appsettings, bin, obj and code.zip